Approval process flow not triggered when guest user created record but it is triggered when admin create records how to resolve
Approval process flow not triggered when guest user created record but it is triggered when admin create records how to resolve like wise attached file inserted in org when admin create records but not inserting when guest user creating records

Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please [edit] your post to include the approval process details and the specific troubleshooting you have done.
